# Can a local multiplayer iOS game display differently for each device?

Tags: ios, multiplayer

I've seen games which display different data for two devices, but not more than two.

If possible, can it be accomplished using GameKit?

EDIT:
More specifically, I was thinking local multiplayer via bluetooth or wi-fi on an iOS device. Most games I've seen display the same screen synchronized across all of the devices.

I understand games that network across the internet do this, often using a server, but I haven't seen any examples of a 3+ device local multiplayer iOS game. I just want to make sure it wasn't some kind of limitation.

Comment: could you please explain more, what do you mean display different data?

Comment: By "display different data", I mean the graphics shown on each device is different. Each device is in a different state. Not synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course. The devices are communicating data so they're both kept up to date on each other (or at least, on the information you choose to share). They are *not* necessarily keeping absolutely in synch, and nothing is saying they must use that data in the exact same way. There's nothing stopping you from displaying that data completely differently between the two apps - just program your app that way. Each device has its completely individual app running, completely separate from the others, and it can do what it wants.

After all, how could you possibly have, say, a multiplayer game with fog of war if your games weren't displaying data differently?

As for the "more than two" - I don't quite understand what you're implying since you're not communicating well, but again it's just a matter of what data you want to share and what you want to display and how.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess it's just a convention in game design to synchronize the display, nothing linked with the programming of it.

Comment: It's not so much a convention as an optional mechanic used in those games where it would be useful to keep the screens synched for whatever reason.